# How to clear the command line in Octave?

Tags: command-line, octave

In Octave, when typing command in the command line, sometimes I need to erase the whole line and restart a new command. In Matlab, erasing the text would be done with the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key. In Octave this does not work. The only way I found to discard the input text is using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. This works, but it is ugly, as it leaves remains on the screen.

Is there a key combination to clear the line in Octave?

Comment: Well, putting aside the fact that this is a 7-years old question, and the taste of the public in what's appropriate or not for this site may not be the same as it was at the time, then according to the site's Help manifest, I still find it on topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . The number of views and "like"-s to the answers and question would suggest that as well.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are several clearing shortcuts defined:

- <kbd>Meta-D</kbd>: clear the next word<sup>1</sup>
- <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>: clear to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>: clear the whole line
- <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>: clear the line and the screen

See more examples in the `octave` [command-line-editing section](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing) of the manual.

For historical reasons <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> is usually controlled by your terminal rather than `octave`, although `octave` also supports it. You can test this with `stty kill undef` (restore with `stty kill '^U'`).

<sub><sup>1</sup> <kbd>Meta</kbd> is often bound to the <kbd>Win</kbd> key or the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. If not hit the Esc key first and then the character that needs to be "metaified".</sub>

Answer (score 130):

to clear the command window **type**:

```
clc
```

Comment: Also what i was looking for

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd>: go to beginning of line.

<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>: kill all characters starting at the cursor.

Comment: Thanks. I also tried some combinations, but after getting used to the `ESC` key, these all feel unintuitive... I guess $2,500 do buy you some ease-of-use, don't they 8-) ?

Comment: BTW, this is similar to `Home`+`Ctrl-K`, but the `C-A-K` is more "natural" to my fingers.

Comment: Well, I also don't like how the command line behaves, but qtoctave is a good alternative. There at least you have typical use&feel, so you can use Shift+Home, Del.

Comment: Oh-Mama! This is so much better. Thanks for pointing out the QtOctave! The only annoyance is that the command line is separated from the actual console, but it is not something that one can't get used to easily 8-)

Comment: **Ctrl-U** is shorter. Also see the [readline manual](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html#SEC3).

Comment: @Thor - this is exactly what I was looking for - make it an answer and I'll rep you (and even select that answer b/c it best answers the question, I think). However, reading through the chapter in the docs, I couldn't find this key combination. Where is it documented? http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Editing.html#Command-Line-Editing

Comment: Here is a non-broken link to [a list of redline shortcuts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline)